# Eclipse's variables window is populated extremely slowly by gdb

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I've just started working on a large C++ project. When I debug my C++ code in Eclipse CDT via GDB, it takes forever to populate the variables window - probably because it shows all the variables in *scope*, which for this specific application includes tons of globals.

The result of this is that everything that involves refreshing this view - e.g. moving to the next line - takes about a full minute when the variables window is open. When it's closed it has sane performance.

So meanwhile I don't use it and get by with hover view and expression view, but having some sort of variable window would be convenient. Is there a way to either

1. Fix the performance of that window, or
2. Somehow limit the variables that are displayed there (e.g. only in immediate scope) so that it will update in reasonable time?

Answer (score 1):

Strange enough, decreasing the number of hops the GUI had to go through - e.g. running Eclipse via ssh **or** VNC, instead of through both at the same time - has significantly improved the performance. I guess this is related to some GUI-updating mechanism in Eclipse.